# Using facet_grid to plot multiple spatial polygons with common polygon as overlay

Tags: ggplot2, r-sf, facet-grid

I want to plot spatial data from a `SpatialPolygonDataframe`. More specifically I want to plot single spatial features in single subplots using `facet_grid()` of `ggplot2`. In addition I'd like to plot a common spatial polygon as overlay in each of the facets.

Here an example using a spatial dataset of the USA and its single states. Each state (of the subset) should be displayed in a single facet) while the outline of the USA (provided in another spatial dataset) should be plotted as overlay in each facet. With my current attempt, also the USA outline is split (based on ID) and spread across the facets:

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

usa <- as(st_as_sf(maps::map(database="usa",fill=T, plot =FALSE)),"Spatial")
usa_states <- as(st_as_sf(maps::map(database="state",fill=T, plot =FALSE)),"Spatial")
usa_states <- usa_states[c(1:5),]

ggplot(data=usa_states)+
  geom_polygon(data=usa, aes(x = long, y = lat,group=id), 
               size = 1, colour = "red",fill=NA)+
  geom_polygon(data=usa_states, aes(x = long, y = lat,group=id), 
               size = 0.3, fill = "green",color="black",alpha=0.2)+
  facet_grid(facets= id ~.)
```

How can I specify that fact_grid only considers 'id' of the usa_states dataset and does not split up the usa outline?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution. There's no need to transform `sf` to `sp`. You can use `geom_sf` function. The problem was because your `id` values are have the same names in both datasets.

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

usa <- st_as_sf(maps::map(database="usa",fill=T, plot =FALSE))
usa_states <- st_as_sf(maps::map(database="state",fill=T, plot =FALSE))
usa_states <- usa_states[c(1:5),]

usa_states <- usa_states %>% 
  rename(id = ID)

ggplot(data = usa_states)+
  geom_sf(size = 0.3, fill = "green",color="black",alpha=0.2)+
  geom_sf(data = usa ,
               size = 1, colour = "red",fill=NA) +
  facet_wrap(~ id)
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, my original data are based on a SpatialPolygonsDataframe; that's why I want to use geom_polygon and that's why I created the example that way. rename() does not work with Spdf.

Comment: Back-transforming the Spdf to a sf object (st_to_sf) and using geom_sf is probably the easiest way to go I assume

Comment: You can also take a look at `tmap` package. It may be easier to plot facets with `spdf` there. See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmap/vignettes/tmap-getstarted.html#facets

Comment: However, I suggest you to plot `sf` objects. It way more easier))